# LINE Login で「正常に処理できませんでした。」と表示される。

Tags: android, kotlin, line

LINE developerの公式ドキュメントを参照しながらLINE channelの作成、LINE SDKの導入、LINE Loginボタンの作成を行ったのですが、
いざボタンを押して見ると「正常に処理できませんでした。」と出力され、「確認」と押すとLogin Resultに"CANCEL"が返ってきます。
解決方法をご存知のかた、ご教授いただけると幸いです。

参考にした公式ドキュメントです。
このサイト通りに実装しています。（コードは特に書き換えていません。）
https://developers.line.me/ja/docs/line-login/android/integrate-line-login/

ちなみに、レスポンスは

```
E/ERROR: LineLoginResult{errorData=LineApiError{httpResponseCode=-1, message=''}, responseCode=CANCEL, lineProfile=null, lineCredential=null}
```

と返ってきています。

Comment: コードやエラーメッセージ等を質問に加えることはできますか？

Comment: Daichi Itokazuさん。質問内容を編集いたしました

Comment: アプリのパッケージ名を間違えていました。プロダクトフレーバーでdevelopment用のパッケージ名を使用しなければいけないところをproduction用のパッケージ名を用いていました。

Comment: 回答して、自分の回答をベストアンサーにしてください！他の人の助けになるかもしれません :)

Comment: Daichiさん。かしこまりました！助言いただきありがとうございます！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

自己解決いたしました。

パッケージ名を間違えていたことが原因でした。
プロダクトフレーバーでパッケージ名を使い分けていたのにもかかわらず、リリース用のパッケージ名を用いていたため、うまく動作しませんでした。
みなさんもパッケージ名を（証明書を発行している場合はSHA-1も）しっかり確認した上で実行してみてください。（私はあっているはずだと他の解決策を模索していたせいで、このバグ解決に3日要しました…）